# magnific popup dosen't show buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have installed magnific popup in my wordpress project, but when I open the popup it does not show me the arrows, the close button, in short, all the buttons that should appear! I have inspected the source and the js and css files are inserted correctly , I also initialized the plug in I leave the code below

```
(function ($) {

  $('.gallery').each(function() { 
    $(this).magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', 
        type: 'image',
        gallery: {
          enabled:true
        }
    });
  });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Inspect elements, search for the button css classes that magnific popup use, if it doesn't exists then it's js issue, if it exists then check the element style, there should be css conflicts that doesn't show you the buttons.

Comment: when I inspect to see precisely if I find the buttons, I only see the popup image, no trace of any buttons! there are not even errors reported by the inspector! it seems that the CSS is not read

Comment: It's hard to debug this kind of issue without a demo. You won't get any kind of errors in this case. What might be happening is that the buttons are loading, css is loading, but your theme or any other plugin applying some other css on top of popup css hence you can't see the button even if it exists. Just to sure you need to find `mfp-arrow-right` or `mfp-arrow-left` class via inspect element, those are the classes that buttons have.

Comment: I deactivated all the plugins, of which I only have one, I also tried to delete the css file which gives me the same result! it seems that the css is not read! I also tried to download the previous version of the css file and not even that works! I just can't understand why! mfp-arrow-right and mfp-arrow-left are not really displayed even in the inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, you have to make sure that in the worpress gallery created, there is the "gallery" class! in my case it wasn't there and I had to add it!